# Where to store methods that relate to the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I hope this hasn't been answered already, but I don't even know what to search for.

I have an MVC project, and I need to return a list of users from the DB. Simple enough. But I only want to return certain users. Again, simple stuff.

What has me confused is that I don't know where I should put the code for that. If I put it in the controller I end up with the same code in multiple methods, and spread over multiple controllers.

I've currently put the method to return the users in my dbcontext class. That works and seems to make sense, but I wonder if there's a better way to do it? That class would end up getting massive in a bigger project.

I've looked at using repository classes, but that just seems to be adding an additional layer. I'm using EF6, and not doing any unit testing (yet)

The code below shows the structure of my dbcontext class (I've edited out the actual code, to keep it brief).

```
public class LeadsDB :DbContext
{
    public LeadsDB()
        : base("Leads")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetUserList(bool includeBlank = true)
    {
        return UserList;
    }
}
```

Comment: A repository would be your next logical step, there. That layer is good. Stands between business logic and database access code.

Comment: IMO your `LeadsDB` class is fine, absolutely no point in adding another abstraction on top of that.

Comment: @mxmissile, you don't know how big his solution is going to get, so suggesting that there is *absolutely* no point in adding another layer of abstraction is narrow-minded. There are no radical answers... depending on what he's doing and how big his solution is going to get, there are different ways of achieving what he's trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they say:

> All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection... Except for the problem of too many layers of indirection.

So depending on the size and scope of your app, you need to decide how many layers of indirection will let you hit the sweet spot of maintainability for your application.

If your application is going to be really small, go ahead and put those methods on your context directly. If it's going to be big enough for your DbContext to become unmaintainable, I'd create repositories. And so forth.

In the application I'm working on, we only interact with Entity Framework for data-related operations. All of our repositories return DTOs which are abstractions of our data model. Our Controllers further convert most of our DTOs into ViewModels before passing them to the Views. And there's a "Manager" layer between the controllers and the repositories to handle business logic and security-checking. We end up with a lot of layers, but we've found value in decoupling the view, presentation, business, security, and data models.

Comment: Thanks StriplingWarrior, and everybody else that replied.  This project is going to be reasonably small, so I'll just keep doing what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an Entity Framework DBContext; if so, then use this as your Data Layer.

Possibly consider using a "Business Layer" abstraction model to do additional things to your objects. Your data access layer should do **just** that: work with data.

If you have, say, a singleton class as your business layer, then you could use your data layer to directly work with the data, and then the business layer to apply business logic to that data and return it to your presentation layer (be it a website, a windows form, etc.)

The business logic layer could possibly check for the data in cache and if it doesn't exist, then retrieve it from your data layer, put it in cache and return it to your presentation layer.